# Hosting Angular App in chrome doesnt work

Tags: python, angularjs, google-chrome, flask

I am trying to host an app in my local network and i am facing issues.
I am a fairly new guy to front-end technologies, i have just started with angular-js.

I have the setup as python-flask API for providing me the data on "**127.0.0.1:5000/**" or "**{myip}:5000/**".

The app seems to be working on both chrome and IE when i access it as
http://**127.0.0.1:8000/app/index.html#/**.
But when i launch this on http://**{mpip}:8000/app/index.html#/**, the app does not allow me to login saying authentication failed, only in chrome.

No body in my network including me can login to link on chrome where the link with ip(my machine's ip) is used.

I have handled the cross domain issue for chrome with the decorator available @ http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/

Thank for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell flask to run the application on all public ip addresses on your network.

Update your app.run() call read `app.run("0.0.0.0")`.

More info here (see section "Externally Visible Server"): http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/

Comment: No, it didnt work on chrome, besides its working in IE already.

Comment: it might have something related to CORS. do you have them enabled?

Comment: I have tried that too, no difference. could you please tell me how its working with no issues inIE?